Validation Rules for Non-Empty Strings with express-validator Not Working as Expected
ValidationChain Express-validator not working when use obj config
Anyone can help me for this problem. I have two this property. "Status" not working when my req.body.status="", but type still work truthly. [enter image description here].
Here is config of two this (https://i.sstatic.net/1KYwNpv3.png). I use "express-validator" module npm nodejs

I tried add NotEmpty
But still not working
Server response
Server still return empty Status and not check another validate
Here is my routes

You need to add the notEmpty method to the schema definition to disallow empty strings

but when I not use Obj, I used directly ValidationChain, it worked correct
